# Powershell Get-Service (Stop) but NOT display status "waiting for <x> service to stop..."

Tags: powershell, suppressmessage

Basically, I don't have an issue with the action being taken. My question is about the status output of the action "waiting for..." message. Is there a way to suppress that message?

Example:

```
PS C:\Users\a.real.person.maybe> Get-Service *fewserviceswithmatchingprefixes* | Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch 'somethinghere' -and $_.Name -ne 'alsosomethinghere' -and $_.Name -ne 'somethinghereprobably'} | Stop-Service
WARNING: Waiting for service 'thoseservicesabove' to stop...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'anotheroneofthoseservicesabove' to stop...
```

[image]

Comment: `Stop-Service -WarningAction SilentlyContinue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set the value of the `$WarningActionPreference` variable at the callsite to `Ignore` or `SilentlyContinue` (both will suppress consumption and rendering of the warning message):

```
$WarningActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Get-Service *fewserviceswithmatchingprefixes* | Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch 'somethinghere' -and $_.Name -ne 'alsosomethinghere' -and $_.Name -ne 'somethinghereprobably'} | Stop-Service
```

Or you can use the `-WarningAction` common parameter explicitly when making the call to `Stop-Service` (it will only affect that particular invocation of `Stop-Service`):

```
... | Stop-Service -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 1):

@mathias in comments hit the nail on the head!

bunch of stuff | Stop-Service -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75112377/45375):

You can **alternatively** use a `3>` redirection, namely **`3>$null` to silence warnings**:

```
... | Stop-Service 3>$null
```

PowerShell's [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) are numbered (with streams `1` (success), and `2` (error) corresponding to the system-level stdout and stderr streams when communicating with the outside world), and `3` refers to the *warning stream*, which can be targeted `>`, the [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection); redirecting to `$null` effectively *discards* the targeted stream's output, if any.

This works with any of the output streams (`>` being implicitly the same as `1>`, i.e. targeting the *success* output stream), and PowerShell even offers redirection **`*>`** to redirect *all* streams.
Targeting a *file name or path* rather than `$null` (quietly) saves the stream output to a plain-text file with the same formatting you would see in the terminal, except that stream-specific prefixes such as "WARNING: " are omitted.

Using something like **`3>` has one advantage** over using the [common `-WarningAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-warningaction):

- Only *cmdlets* and [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) functions and scripts support `-WarningAction`, whereas **`3>$null` is also effective with *simple* functions and scripts that use [`Write-Warning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-warning)**.

  - By contrast, the [`$WarningPreference` *preference variable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#warningpreference) is equally effective for *all* PowerShell commands.
  - However, preference variables, notably the [`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference), do *not* apply to *external programs*: streams `3` and higher *do not apply* to external programs, and an external program's *stderr* output is (sensibly) *not* considered error output by default (though such output can be targeted as stream number `2`); **to silence an external program's *stderr* output, you *must* use `2>$null`**
  - As an aside: Additional warning-related functionality that is also only supported by cmdlets and advanced functions/scripts is the ability to collect warnings in a *variable*, via the [common `-WarningVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-warningvariable); the closest approximation of this functionality with a `3>` redirection is to target a *file* to write the warnings to (which would necessitate displaying that file's content after the fact to also *print* the warnings).
- While *technically distinct*, a stream-targeted redirection such as `3>` should *behave the same* as the equivalent `-WarningAction SilentlyContinue` parameter, and - with the exception of `2>` / `-ErrorAction` - equally applies to `-*Action Ignore`.

  - `-ErrorAction Ignore` -like `2>$null` / `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` - suppresses error-stream *output*, but - unlike the latter - *additionally* prevents the (non-terminating) errors that occur from *getting recorded in the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error)*, which is a session-wide collection of errors that have occurred so far.
  - In rare edge cases (for reasons unknown to me), `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` can *fail* to record `$Error`, whereas `2>$null` still does - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75045300/45375) for an example.